# ITextSharp Defining a Pages Background Image: Whats the correct way?

Tags: c#, pdf, itext

**Is it possible to set a background image for a pdf page in ITextSharp?**

Whats the correct way to define a background image for a pdf page? Is there a property of the document I set?

Or is it just like creating another image(my image has the dimensions of a A4 page)? *If I add the background image as a normal image will I be able to place paragraphs over the top of the background image?*

```
var document = new Document(PageSize.A4, 50, 50, 25, 25);
// Create a new PdfWrite object, writing the output to a MemoryStream
var output = new MemoryStream();
var writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, output);
var logo = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(Server.MapPath("~/Images/test.jpg"));
logo.SetAbsolutePosition(0,0);
document.Add(logo);

// Will the following paragraph be ON TOP or below the background image? 
// I am aiming for on top
document.Add( new Paragraph("sjfkkjdsfk") ); 
document.Close();
```

Answer (score 0):

The logo is fine - it's just a regular image content on the page, not backgound img (like in HTML). To put content on top of that, you need to use Direct Content:

```
PdfContentByte over = writer.DirectContent;
over.SaveState();
over.BeginText();
over.SetFontAndSize(BaseFont.CreateFont(), 9);        
over.ShowTextAligned(Element.ALIGN_LEFT, "Your Text", x, y, 0);
over.SetLineWidth(0.3f);        
over.EndText();
over.RestoreState();
```

Please note the x and y cord are from the bottom left corner. The last parameter is for rotation.

Another tip: do a doc.NewPage(); if you want to start a new page with the image background, so the the text cord is on the new page.